# Adobe Brackets: Remove some auto-complete sugestions

Tags: autocomplete, adobe-brackets

I'd like to know if it's possible to customize the auto-complete options that Adobe Brackets give when coding.

For example, in a CSS file, whenever I type "w" it gives me the some sugestions like "white-space, windows, widht".
I've never used white-space or windows... and it would be much better to remove those 2 options so that "width" (that I use a lot) would be the first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **really** annoyed by unnecessary code suggestions, then you will have to *hack* Brackets. Don’t worry, it’s fairly easy:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/adobe/brackets.git
$ cd brackets/
$ ./tools/setup_for_hacking.(bat|sh)
```

More info can be found at the official Brackets wiki: [How to hack on Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Hack-on-Brackets#quick-start).

Now you can edit the code suggestions for CSS, which are located at `src/extensions/default/CSSCodeHints/CSSProperties.json`. Don’t forget to reload Brackets in order to apply your changes!

Comment: In my version it wasn't actually necessary to do the "hacking" part. I just edited the .json file and that was it. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, I thought changing the order would do the trick. Tried moving 'float' before 'flex' and 'filter' properties. But that didn't work :(